# Entity Framework Code First - Changing a Table Name

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I want to change the name of one of my tables generated using Entity Framework code first.

I have already created the database, but now I want to change the name. I've updated all references to the `"Metadatas"` table to `"Metadata"` in my project. But the table that is being generated in the database is still "Metadatas". I've dropped and re-created the database, but that doesn't seem to work either. Neither does using a TableAttribute.   What I'm I supposed to do?

Thanks.

```
[Table("Metadata")]
public class Metadata 
{
    [Required, Key]
    public int MetadataId { get; set; }

    [Required, ScaffoldColumn(false)]
    public int DocumentId { get; set; }

    [Required, StringLength(250), DataType(DataType.Text)]
    public string Title { get; set; }
```

...

Comment: `Table` should definitely do the job. Make sure you're checking the right database, not the old one. Happens to everybody.

Answer (score 78, accepted):

You have two options here:

Data Annotations:

```
//Changing database table name to Metadata
[Table("Metadata")]
public class Metadata 
{
  [Required, Key]
  public int MetadataId { get; set; }

  [Required, ScaffoldColumn(false)]
  public int DocumentId { get; set; }

  [Required, StringLength(250), DataType(DataType.Text)]
  public string Title { get; set; 
}
```

or we have Fluent API:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
  //Changing Database table name to Metadata
  modelBuilder.Entity<Metadata>()
      .ToTable("Metadata");
}
```

Using the Fluent API is the preferred option if you want to ensure your Domain Model stays uncluttered.

Just adding to this, if you solely want to remove the pluralisation of your table names, you can override EFs ability to do so with the following line of code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
}
```

Comment: Why is it that the table that is created in the database is called "Metadatas", not "Metadata"? I think that is why I am confused...

Comment: Entity Framework will pluralise the name of your class as the way in which it looks at it, if you have a class called 'Dog", for example, when several Dog objects persisted to a database, you'll have a collection of "Dogs". I can see your issues though as Metadata is both singular and plural. You'd have the same issue if you had a class called "Fish" (a table called "Fishs").

Comment: Ok. I get it. I know its not a big deal, but the "metadatas" was driving me nuts. So the way above is the way around that behavior? I couldn't get it to drop the "s".

Comment: Yeh, that's the way. I'd recommend using the fluent api version, but both methods should work

Comment: I think I'm losing my marbles....I just googled "How to rename database table in Entity Framework", came to this StackOverflow question and realised I was the one who answered it months ago! :)

Comment: This goes in the `DBContext` derived class, fyi

Comment: @Stu1986C your last comment make me LAMO, any way the answer saved my morning ;)

Comment: The data annotation worked for me, however I needed to delete the migration that contained the improper table name first so it's one to bear in mind

Comment: For the fluent API approach, if you get `EntityTypeBuilder<> does not contain a definition for 'ToTable'...` you will need to install the package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43200184/entitytypebuilder-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-totable-in-ef-core

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `DbSet<T>` property on your `DbContext`, that is one place that EF can get the table name from. Rename that property and run a new migration to rename the table.