# EntityTypeBuilder does not contain a definition for ToTable in EF Core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have this sample code:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;
using Models;

namespace MySampleNamespace
{
    public class MyDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            new UserMap(modelBuilder.Entity<User>());
        }

        public class UserMap
        {
            public UserMap(EntityTypeBuilder<User> entityBuilder)
            {
                entityBuilder.ToTable("User");
                entityBuilder.Property(s => s.Username).HasMaxLength(15).IsRequired();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I was testing out some example from MS website, but I can't find ToTable method. In the example, I checked what are the Usings and the only Using the example had is Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore aside from the class project for the model he was using. Was this changed? How do I do this now?

Comment: Make sure you have reference to Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational assembly. The usings are ok - the method in question is extension method defined in `RelationalEntityTypeBuilderExtensions` class under `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` namespace in that assembly.

Answer (score 320, accepted):

Installing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational` is the correct solution, as Ivan says.

Comment: @GertArnold fixed

Comment: HasColumnName is also in this nuget package.  I was migrating some DotNet Framework code and thought I was going crazy.  Thanks!  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational/

Comment: I have no idea why intellisense is failing to suggest this missing nuget package. Either let users add all packages manually, or work perfectly. Bad intellisense.

Answer (score 33):

You should add the nuget package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`, since this is a Microsoft SQL method.

Answer (score 15):

I had this problem, but did not need to install:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
```

I simply exited VS 2017 and re-opened my solution.
I had the following NuGet packages installed:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
```

And the following CLI Tool Reference:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet
```

Answer (score 15):

For net core 3.1, need to install these packages:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational
```

Answer (score 9):

Porting from EF6 to EFCore, we had this issue. Our cause was `.HasKey` now returns a `KeyBuilder` and the `.ToTable` doesn't operate on it. So reversing that worked.

Ie. Was:

```
mp.HasKey(m => m.Id)
  .ToTable("Table")
```

Became:

```
mp.ToTable("Table")
  .HasKey(m => m.Id);
```

Comment: Working now, this was it for me.

Answer (score 9):

Ivan & Mardoxx are correct.

I tried to just install `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`  then got this error:

> Detected package downgrade: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore from 2.1.4 to 2.1.1. Reference the package directly from the project to select a different version. 
>   -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.1.4 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 2.1.4 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 2.1.4 -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.1.4)  -> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore (>= 2.1.1)

1. I upgraded Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore via nuget
2. I did install Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools which didn't work for `ToTable` , unknown if this is even needed
3. I did then install the `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational`  and it now resolves

Comment: I also followed your steps and upgraded <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework> from netcoreapp2.1 now Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational are successfully installed but the using statement doesnot show a "Relational" namespace after Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore and therefore i am unable to use MapToStoredProcedures :S

Answer (score 7):

For EFCore 3.1 I needed to use this in my DB context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        foreach (IMutableEntityType entity in modelBuilder.Model.GetEntityTypes())
        {
            entity.SetTableName("WS_" + entity.GetTableName());
        }
    }
```

No additional Nuget package was required.

Answer (score 5):

Install

- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore`,
- `MicrosoftEntityFramworkCore.Tools`, and finally
- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer`

Answer (score 4):

For me, my issue was that I trying to call ToView() incorrectly.

I was doing:

```
 modelBuilder.Query<Vendor>(entity =>
        {
            entity.Property(v => v.VendorId).HasColumnName("VendorID");
            entity.Property(v => v.Name).HasColumnName("Vendor Name");                
        }).ToView("vwVendors");
```

instead of:

```
modelBuilder.Query<Vendor>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToView("vwVendors");
            entity.Property(v => v.VendorId).HasColumnName("VendorID");
            entity.Property(v => v.Name).HasColumnName("Vendor Name");                
        });
```

Answer (score 4):

Ensure that the correct project is selected in the "Default Project" dropdown, and then type the command below :

```
install-package microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserver
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your .Net version you are using. `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet` only supports .NetStandard >= 2.0.

If your .Net version is 4.6.1, update `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` to 2.0.0-preview1-final, along with related EntityFramework DLLs, then close Visual Studio 2017 and re-open.

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible you have version discrepancies in your solution, so for example, if one of the projects in your dependency chain has a `3.1` version of `EF Core` and another project has a `2.1`, then you will also see this error, and no matter what you install it won't work, instead make sure they are the same version in the entire solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package
and write it:

```
builder.ToTable("tblName");
```

Comment: installing Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools package will not serve the purpose. This package enables these commands: Add-Migration, Bundle-Migration, Drop-Database etc. Check this [link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

**Solution**: For me installing `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlserver` solved the issue.

**Additional info**:
I installed `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` first. But it doesn't solve the problem. Because the purpose of this package is different. this package does the following -

```
Enables these commonly used commands:
Add-Migration
Bundle-Migration
Drop-Database
Remove-Migration
Update-Database
```

Check [this link](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools) for more info about `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`