# how can i change table name by fluent API of entity framework code first in c#?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I want to change table name of my c# class by fluent API that it'll must be map on database (SQL Server), and I am using Entity Framework code first as ORM in my project.

Comment: Put some considerable code also.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Code First - Changing a Table Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656617/entity-framework-code-first-changing-a-table-name)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For do that, you can create a folder as a configuration or mapping in your Data model layer, and then add a class like 'className+"Config".cs'. Then inherit that class form 'EntityTypeConfiguration<"MainClassName">' Then in that class you must create a constructor as same as a 'className+Config', and in this constructor you may use:

```
this.ToTable("Your_table_name_In_Sql", schemaName: "Your_Schema_name");
```

After all of them, add your 'className+Config' class to your "DbContext" class As i Mentioned below:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new 'className+Config'());

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, this was very helpful. Thank you!!