# EF Core generates statement with invalid table name

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, sqlexception

I'm trying to get some values with `Include` and `ThenInclude` but EF Core generates a statement with an invalid tablename.

This is my DataContext:

```
public class BaseContext : BaseDbContext 
{
    protected BaseWebsiteContext(DbContextOptions dbContextOptions) : base(dbContextOptions)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Image> Images { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ImageTags> ImageTags { get; set; }
}
```

These are my three datamodels:

```
public class Image : Entity.Entity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Filepath { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateDate { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ImageTags> ImageTags { get; set; } = new List<ImageTags>();
}

public class Tag : Entity.Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public ICollection<ImageTags> ImageTags { get; set; } = new List<ImageTags>();
}

public class ImageTags
{
    public int ImageId { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
}
```

the base-class `Entity` contains the property of primary-key `Id (int)`
In my `OnModelCreating`, I added to define the composite PK.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ImageTags>().HasKey(x => new {x.ImageId, x.TagId});
```

So in my repository, this is my query:

```
return await _dataContext.Images
            .Include(x => x.ImageTags)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Tag)
            .Where(w => w.ImageTags.Any(x => x.TagId == tagId))
            .ToListAsync();
```

And this is what EF generates:

```
SELECT [x.ImageTags].[ImageId], [x.ImageTags].[TagId], [i.Tag].[Id], [i.Tag].[Description], [i.Tag].[Name]
FROM [ImageTags] AS [x.ImageTags]
INNER JOIN [Tags] AS [i.Tag] ON [x.ImageTags].[TagId] = [i.Tag].[Id]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [x1].[Id]
    FROM [Images] AS [x1]
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [ImageTags] AS [x2]
        WHERE ([x2].[TagId] = @__tagId_0) AND ([x1].[Id] = [x2].[ImageId]))
) AS [t] ON [x.ImageTags].[ImageId] = [t].[Id]
ORDER BY [t].[Id]
```

that is wrong, because my table is called `Tag`, not `Tags`, so of course, it throws an SqlException `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid object name 'Tags'.`

Any idea what I did wrong?

**Edit:** I don't want to change the tables name. If I add a migration, EF generates my migration/sql-table. How can it be that there appears an exception?

Comment: `PluralizingTableNameConvention`, related : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656617/entity-framework-code-first-changing-a-table-name

Comment: There's a convention that governs the translation of entity names to table names.  You can override it with a Table attribute, or the Fluent API. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/tables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Code First - Changing a Table Name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656617/entity-framework-code-first-changing-a-table-name)

Comment: @xdtTransform I dont want to change the table name, I want EF to use the same name for the table like the entity is called. Did anything change here in .net core? in EF6 I never had a problem like this

Comment: @xdtTransform I edited my question for this. this is not a duplicate

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `DbContext` `DbSet` for `Tag` is  `public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }`. In EF/EF Core DbContext's `DbSet` properties maps to database table. Hence it is searching table name `Tags` for `Tag` as your `DbSet` for `Tag` is `Tags`.

You can solve it in any of the following ways:

1. `public DbSet<Tag> Tag { get; set; }`
2. Renaming `Tag` table to `Tags`
3. `modelBuilder.Entity<Tag>().ToTable("Tag");`

Comment: Are you sure? Why should it search for a `Tags`-table when the EF migration generates a table called `Tag`?

Comment: @MatthiasBurger Are you sure your migration is generating table name `Tag` for `public DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }`?. It should not be unless you manually override it.

Comment: It does. And no, I won't override any migration :D did that mistake in an old project - never again...

Comment: So possibly simply a bug in EF Core? Never had this problem before.. (neither in EF Core)

Comment: @MatthiasBurger Then this is not the expected behavior of EF/EF Core. May be something went wrong anywhere in your code or configuration.

Comment: @MatthiasBurger What is your EF Core version?

Comment: my version is 2.1.2

Comment: I see your table for `Image` is `Images` generated correctly then how it has been `Tag` for  `Tag` ? instead of `Tags`? Surely you made something wrong. By the way, solve the problem using any of the three solution I have shown.

Comment: did not see that Images is correct and pluralized too. But yes, the migrations did `Images` and `Tag`... strange... I will try to remove and recreate the migration. thx for your help..