# EF Core 6.0.2 || Create table dynamically at run time with custom name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have an entity class with 5 properties. See the class `Person` as an example:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id{ get; set;} 

    [Required]
    public string Name{ get; set;}

    [Required]
    public string Address{ get; set;}

    [Required]
    public string EmailAddress{ get; set;}

    [Required]
    public string MobileNumber { get; set;}
}
```

My requirement is: when an admin creates a group and provides the name, I have to create a new table with the above model class' columns with the name as provided by the admin.

So if admin enters a name like `DelhiPerson`, then a table should be created in the database with name `DelhiPerson` with the same columns as shown in the above `Person` class.

I am using Entity Framework Core 6.0.2

I tried to Google but haven't found any relevant reference. Any reference or tutorial will be helpful.

Comment: you could create table group & table group-person-relation. please reconsider the entity-relation.

Comment: @KennetsuRinn thanks for the suggestion. There will not be any relation with any other entity. I am storing the table name in a separate table and I want to get the data from this table using the store table name

Comment: trying looking into 'custom claims'. that might help.

Comment: @Dharmendra Kumar if you would have to persist to do that, you could create custom Attribute class in which might to save table name, override OnModelCreating funtion in which might to query table name from Attribute class and create new table.

Comment: you can reference [Entity Framework Code First - Changing a Table Name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21664823/15073910) and [Create Table, Run Time using entity framework Code-First](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39807547/15073910)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it through ADO.NET capabilities provided by EF Core.

```
using(var cmd = context.Database.GetDbContext().CreateCommand())
{
   cmd.CommandText = "Create Table SQL Statement here";
   context.Database.OpenConnection();
   var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Ok that will work, but How could we reflect the created table on our backend, I mean adding Entity and creating class on backend ?

Comment: I have an entity class and using that class to fill data and get data from it. For this table only, not using entity framework. If you want, I can send you the code.